# Python ADAL acquire_token_with_client_credentials refresh token?

Tags: python, adal

Is there a reason why the Python ADAL library's authentication method **acquire_token_with_client_credentials** does not return a refresh token? I suppose Daemon apps do not need to use a refresh token each time they run but it seemed odd to me that the other authentication methods do return one.

Code sample:

```
class AzureActiveDirectory_Helper:
_config = Configuration()
_resource = _config.Resource
_graph_api_endpoint = _config.Graph_API_Endpoint
_authority = _config.Authority

def __init__(self):
    self.Context = adal.AuthenticationContext(self._authority)
    self.Token = self.Context.acquire_token_with_client_credentials(
        resource=self._resource,
        client_id=self._config.Client_ID,
        client_secret="thisIsASuperSecretKey!!"
    )

    self.Headers = {
        'Authorization' : f'Bearer {self.Token["accessToken"]}',
        'Accept' : 'application/json',
        'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
    }
```

The values in self.Token do have a `accessToken` value and that token does allow me to do what I need against the Azure AD app but isn't it best practice to use a refresh token instead of acquiring a fresh Token every run?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, I agree that it's a best practice to use a refresh token instead of acquiring a new fresh token every time.

The issuance of a refresh token with the client credential grant has no benefit. That is why the [RFC6749 section 4.4.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.4.3) indicates A refresh token SHOULD NOT be included.

As per the document,"acquire_token_with_client_credentials" returns only access token.

So to use refresh token, python adal library supports other authentication method like:
"acquire_token", "acquire_token_with_refresh_token" etc. You can check the documentation.

Below are the documentation links:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/adal/adal.authentication_context.authenticationcontext?view=azure-python#acquire-token-with-client-credentials-resource--client-id--client-secret-

https://adal-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/